# Portable binary representation of date/time value

Tags: datetime, language-agnostic

I am looking for a way to serialize date/time value in a binary file. However, the serialized presentation should be such that I must be able to deserialize it across platforms (Windows, Linux), architecture (64 bit/32 bit), and programming languages (C#, Java, C++). I am wondering if there are any public domain functions that are already available. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: What about a generally accepted UNIX timestamp, best as 64 bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots and lots of standards for dates and times. [This webpage describes many of these formats](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/). All of these formats can be serialized and deserialized to binary files. Many programming languages have functions that can import, export, and convert these formats.

If you are looking for a very small representation, then 32-bit or 64-bit seconds since a certain date and time might be a good choice. If you can live with a larger representation then you may want to store the date/time in one of the W3C DTF formats. For example the most detailed date/time looks like `1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00`.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up storing it as string.

Answer (score 5):

Use 64-bit milliseconds since UNIX epoch.  Should be good for [a while](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) ;-)  (

Answer (score 3):

Temporenc (http://temporenc.org) is a comprehensive binary encoding format for dates and times.